# Path is still unusable after use of streamreader even though streamreader was closed

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

**UPDATE: I have saved the path in a string and sent it over to the other document,**

I have made a small game for school and everything works as intended, but when the "ITAMons" (that's how we call them) level up an if statement is accessed and a streamwriter is trying to write onto a file which was used by a `streamreader` before, but the `streamreader` was closed and still it says I can't access the file, because it's still in use.

The StreamReaders are defined in the document itself and here they get defined and then used in the ITAMon constructor

```
sr = new StreamReader(Zielordner.Text + "\\" + ITAListe.CheckedItems[0].ToString());
sr2 = new StreamReader(Zielordner.Text + "\\" + ITAListe2.CheckedItems[0].ToString());
ITAMon1 = new ITAMon(sr);
ITAMon2 = new ITAMon(sr2);
```

which has at the end of it `sr.Close()`.

Here's the entire constructor:

```
public ITAMon(StreamReader sr)
{
    ITAName = sr.ReadLine();
    if (ITAName == String.Empty)
    {
        bool falsch = false;
        Debug.Assert(falsch, "Auslesefehler! Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Datei!");
    }
    string[] Auslesung = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
    if (Auslesung.Length > 6)
    {
        switch (Auslesung[0])
        {
            case "Feuer":
                Element = Element.Feuer;
                break;
            case "Wasser":
                Element = Element.Wasser;
                break;
            case "Pflanze":
                Element = Element.Pflanze;
                break;
            default:
                Element = Element.Normal;
                break;
        }
        Level = Convert.ToInt32(Auslesung[1]);
        Leben = Convert.ToDouble(Auslesung[2]);
        CurrentLife = Leben;
        EXP = Convert.ToInt32(Auslesung[3]);
        Look = Auslesung[4];
        BaseDmg = Convert.ToInt32(Auslesung[5]);
        Verteidigung = Convert.ToDouble(Auslesung[6]);
        Geschwindigkeit = Convert.ToDouble(Auslesung[7]);
        Erweitert = true;
    }

    else if (Auslesung.Length < 7)
    {

        switch (Auslesung[0])
        {
            case "Feuer":
                Element = Element.Feuer;
                break;
            case "Wasser":
                Element = Element.Wasser;
                break;
            case "Pflanze":
                Element = Element.Pflanze;
                break;
            default:
                Element = Element.Normal;
                break;
        }
        Level = Convert.ToInt32(Auslesung[1]);
        Leben = Convert.ToDouble(Auslesung[2]);
        CurrentLife = Leben;
        EXP = Convert.ToInt32(Auslesung[3]);
        Look = Auslesung[4];
        Erweitert = false;
    }
    string[] Attacke1 = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
    if (Attacke1.Length != 4)
    {
        bool falsch = false;
        Debug.Assert(falsch, "Auslesefehler! Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Datei!");
    }
    Attacken[0] = new Attacke(Attacke1[0], Convert.ToInt32(Attacke1[1]), Convert.ToInt32(Attacke1[3]), Convert.ToInt32(Attacke1[2]));
    string[] Attacke2 = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
    if (Attacke2.Length != 4)
    {
        bool falsch = false;
        Debug.Assert(falsch, "Auslesefehler! Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Datei!");
    }
    Attacken[1] = new Attacke(Attacke2[0], Convert.ToInt32(Attacke2[1]), Convert.ToInt32(Attacke2[3]), Convert.ToInt32(Attacke2[2]));
    string[] Attacke3 = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
    if (Attacke3.Length != 4)
    {
        bool falsch = false;
        Debug.Assert(falsch, "Auslesefehler! Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Datei!");
    }
    Attacken[2] = new Attacke(Attacke3[0], Convert.ToInt32(Attacke3[1]), Convert.ToInt32(Attacke3[3]), Convert.ToInt32(Attacke3[2]));
    string[] Attacke4 = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
    if (Attacke4.Length != 4)
    {
        bool falsch = false;
        Debug.Assert(falsch, "Auslesefehler! Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Datei!");
    }
    Attacken[3] = new Attacke(Attacke4[0], Convert.ToInt32(Attacke4[1]), Convert.ToInt32(Attacke4[3]), Convert.ToInt32(Attacke4[2]));

    sr.Close();
}
```

Despite the `sr.Close()` it still says the path in use when this if statement is accessed and a `streamwriter` is trying to use the path.

```
    if (ITAMon1.CrtLife <= 0 || ITAMon1.GetAttacken[0].Mgz == 0 & ITAMon1.GetAttacken[1].Mgz == 0 & ITAMon1.GetAttacken[2].Mgz == 0 & ITAMon1.GetAttacken[3].Mgz == 0)
            {


                Pfad = Zielordner.Text + "\\" + ITAListe2.CheckedItems[0].ToString();
                EventLog.Text = ITAMon2.GetName + " Gewinnt!";
                ITAMon2.GetEXP += ITAMon2.GetGegner.GetLevel;
                if(ITAMon2.LvlUp())
                {
                    Gewinner = ITAMon2;
                    MessageBox.Show(ITAMon2.GetName + " hat das nächste Level erreicht!", "LevelUp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    LevelUp levelUp = new LevelUp();
                    levelUp.Show();
                }
                else
                {

                    ITAMon2.Save(Pfad);
                    srG.Close();
                    this.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(ITAMon2.GetName + " Gewinnt!", "Gewinner", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            else if (ITAMon2.CrtLife <= 0 || ITAMon2.GetAttacken[0].Mgz == 0 & ITAMon2.GetAttacken[1].Mgz == 0 & ITAMon2.GetAttacken[2].Mgz == 0 & ITAMon2.GetAttacken[3].Mgz == 0)
        {
                Pfad = Zielordner.Text + "\\" + ITAListe.CheckedItems[0].ToString();
                EventLog.Text = ITAMon1.GetName + " Gewinnt!";
                ITAMon1.GetEXP += ITAMon1.GetGegner.GetLevel;
                if (ITAMon1.LvlUp())
                {
                    Gewinner = ITAMon1;
                    MessageBox.Show(ITAMon1.GetName + " hat das nächste Level erreicht!", "LevelUp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    LevelUp levelUp = new LevelUp();
                    levelUp.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    srG = new StreamWriter(Pfad);
                    ITAMon1.Save(Pfad);
                    srG.Close();
                    this.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(ITAMon1.GetName + " Gewinnt!", "Gewinner", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to fix that? It should be usable, even after I manually wrote `sr.Close()` into the document itself and it still wouldn't work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `bool falsch = false;` I'm so curious why you have these?

Comment: To tell it when to run Debug.Assert.

Comment: You can just assert on `false`, or better yet, the actual condition you are asserting.